# How to show compact layout when mouse hover on a field value in lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a requirement to show compact layout on mouse hover on a column field values in lightning:datatable. For example, lets say you have Created By column in lighting:datatable, when you mouse hover on the field value of Created By need to show compact layout fields of the user record.

Currently one way to do it is by using custom type datatable for Created By field and where I can define what to do when mouse hover. Other way is instead of using lightning:datatable use template loop on the fields.

Is there any better way of achieving it?

Comment: What's "worse" about the options you cited as doable?

Comment: I'd use the custom type approach. Documented and generally works well.